# Оптимизация экрана на iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Создал приложение для iOS 7.

Попробовал запустить его на iPhone 5 с iOS 6: выглядит будто запущено на айфоне4-4с с черными полосами сверху и снизу.

В .xib-файлах установлен параметр: "Freeform".
Как отображать приложение правильно, на весь экран?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавить к проекту файл с именем Default-h568@2x.png и разрешением 640X1136.